# Tangent space of hyperboloid

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Given the Minkowski-metric $I$ with $I(x,x)=-x_0^2+x_1^2+...+x_n^2$. The set of upper plane of a two sheet hyperboloid is given by $\Bbb H:=\{x\in\Bbb R^{n+1}|I(x,x)=-1, x_0>0\}$. The corresponding tagent space at p is thus $T_p\Bbb H:=\{y\in \Bbb R^{n+1}|I(p,y)=0\}$.

**Question:**
If I want to compute the tangent plane at $p=(1,0,...,0)$, acoording to the definition, I would obtain a plane at $x_0=0$. However, we would expect a plane at $x_0=1$ as the point $p$ has to lie in the tangent space $T_p\Bbb H$. Did I misunderstood something?

Comment: The corresponding tagent space at p is thus $T_p\Bbb H:=\{y\in \Bbb R^{n+1}|I(p,y)=\color{red}{-1}\}$. I think you haven't done the distinction between vector tangent plane and affine tangent plane. A hint: the equation of the (affine) tangent plane in $p$ is obtained by taking the bginning of Taylor expansion in a vicinity of $p$.

Comment: @JeanMarie So $I(p,x)=0$ is only valid for affine tangent space? Because this is the definition we are given to. Basically we have to identify $x=x’-p$ then?

Comment: $I(p,x)=0$ is clearly a $\color{red}{\text{linear}}$ relationship, thus it describes the $\color{red}{\text{linear}}$ tangent plane. For your second question that I would not link with a "then", yes the Taylor expansion in $p$ uses $x=x'-p$.

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you for your answer. Very intuitive and clear. I used the word ‘then’ because I think there is a relationship between a tangent vector $x’$ from a vector tangent space and $x$ from an affine tangent space by $x=x’-p$. Is it true?

Comment: Yes, it's true.